# Does anyone know how to add a triangle to gtk/opengl?

Tags: c, opengl, gtk3

I am trying to put opengl into gtk. I got my window working and i have a gl_area. I tried to look for solutions, but I can only add a window with a gl_area to my code, I can't seem to add a triangle to the window. This is what i got so far.

```
#include <gtk/gtk.h>
#include <GL/gl.h>
#include <GL/glut.h>


/*This is my setup for opengl, I can only get glClearColor to work.*/
static gboolean render(GtkGLArea *area, GdkGLContext *context)
{
    glClearColor(.1, .1, .1, 1);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    /*This is commented out because it doesn't work.
    glColor3f(.9, .9, .9);
    glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
        glVertex3f(.50, .75, 0);
        glVertex3f(.25, .25, 0);
        glVertex3f(.75, .25, 0);
    glEnd();

    glFlush();
    */

    return TRUE;
}

//This is my gtk setup.
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    GtkWidget *window, *gl_area;

    gtk_init(&argc, &argv);

    window = gtk_window_new(GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);
    gtk_window_set_title(GTK_WINDOW(window), "Testing");
    gtk_window_set_default_size(GTK_WINDOW(window), 500,500);
    gtk_window_set_resizable(GTK_WINDOW(window), TRUE);
    g_signal_connect(window, "destroy", G_CALLBACK(gtk_main_quit), NULL);

    gtk_container_set_border_width(GTK_CONTAINER(window), 10);

    //These two lines setup opengl
    gl_area = gtk_gl_area_new();
    g_signal_connect(gl_area, "render", G_CALLBACK(render), NULL);

    gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(window), gl_area);
    gtk_widget_show_all(window);
    gtk_main();

    return 0;

}
```

Can anyone help me with this, Thanks.

Comment: Did you comment out the polygon drawing code because it seemed not to work? ... So you did not notice that you were drawing the triangle in the same color as your background?

Comment: Whoops, re edited it. Yes I did comment it out because it doesn't work and it still doesn't work even when changing the color.